# Why does my route handler fires twice?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

One of my router handlers get consistently triggered twice. Although I can clearly see the route trigger is fired only once.  I am using Marionette AppRouter class like this:

```
  MainRouter = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        appRoutes: {
            "home": "showHome",
            "view/:num(/:rev)(/:ms)": "viewSmart",   //smart route
            "*route": "showHome" //any other unrecognized routes
        },
        controller: routesController
    });
```

and controller with handlers:

```
  routesController = {
        showHome: function () {
            console.info('go home');
        },
       viewSmart: function (num, rev, ms) {
            console.log('view route action triggered');
        },...more routes
```

While testing this anomaly I found that the last optional param in the viewSmart method is the root cause. If I navigate to a route without (/:ms) the same method fires once, with it twice.

Answer (score 3):

I traced down this issue to a parameter string that contains a space character. Since backbone uses regex under covers to figure out which route to navigate to the space character throws it for a loop. I am guessing other special characters would too. I don't know why exactly the route handler would get fired twice, but if I just replaced the blank space characters with a plus sign for example things went back to normal. I just had to remember to replace the plus sign back out with the space.

Before navigate:

```
ms = ms.replace(/ /g, '+');
```

After:

```
viewSmart: function (num, rev, ms) {
            console.log('view route action triggered');
            if (ms){
                ms = ms.replace(/\+/g, ' '); // '+' was used to sub for a space 
            }
```